# How do I bind a class if the input type attribute is checkbox? + Vuejs

Tags: javascript, binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following line of code in my .vue template for an input field component which I want to check for whether an input field is a checkbox and bind a class on the input field if it is true.

In the component it looks like this:

```
<input :type="type" class="o-pf-input" :class="!isCheckbox ? 'o-pf-input--cbx' : ''" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="placeholder" :value = 'value' @input="value = $event.target.value">
```

Where it has `:class="!isCheckbox ? 'o-pf-input--cbx' : ''"`

in my data option I have this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        value: '',
        checkbox: 'o-pf-input--cbx',
        isCheckbox: false
    }
},
```

So it is kind of working but it applies the class to all input fields which is what I don't want to achieve. It should only add the class when the attribute type is a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `type` is a prop?
I would move the logic to a computed property and check if `type` is checkbox:

```
computed: {
  checkboxClass: function () {
    return this.type === 'checkbox' ? 'o-pf-input--cbx' : ''
  }
}
```

Which is then used:

```
<input :type="type" class="o-pf-input" :class="checkboxClass" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="placeholder" :value = 'value' @input="value = $event.target.value">
```

You can read more about computed properties here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

If `type` isn't known you might have to get a reference to the actual element and check the type manually. See here for a reference on ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Yip. Type is a prop. I have passed it as a prop in the template.

Comment: Thanks @awnton. Worked like a bomb.

Answer (score 0):

First, try getting rid of the double class specification. Put your static classes as literals in the bound class, ie `:class="['type',!isCheckbox...]"`. If this gets complicated, remove it to a specific function in your `methods`.

Next, instead of an isCheckbox property, why don't you test the `type` variable, so there's one source of truth.

Next, if you want to pass different inputs to different instances of the same component, you will want to use `props`, not `data`. Data will be the same for all instances.

Lastly, are you sure you want put checkboxes and other inputs together in one component? What do they have in common? This looks a bit like cutting a pizza into rectangles.